# Touch Typing Program. What is the tag type of numbers?

Tags: c#

This is my code.

```
private void form_onKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{   
    highlightKeyPressed(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    //if user pressed shift both shift buttons are highlighted
    if (buttonShift2.BackColor == Color.BlueViolet)
    {
        buttonShift1.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
    }
}
private void form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
    {
        resetColors();
    }
}
```

It works for letters and for 0 but not for other numbers.

I used the tag property for the letters. What is the tag for numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thes are the tag's for numbers:

1- D1
2 -D2
3 -D3
4-D4
5-D5
6-D6
7-D7
8-D8
9-D9

0-0 that's why the 0 worked.